# Prove that $\sqrt {n} = \omega(\log(n)^{2})$

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

Just trying to prove this assymptotic connection.
Tried to use the same trick as when I proved that $\sqrt n = O(\log(n)
)$ but it didn't work for me.

*My attempt:*

I tried to use this trick:
[image]

After using it, I am getting this expression: $4\log(\sqrt n)^{2}$ and I am not seeing how you can prove this one is $O(\sqrt n)$.

Comment: $\sqrt{n}$ is not $O(\log(n))$ as $n\to\infty$. Your calculation show the opposite: that $\log(n)$ is $O(\sqrt{n})$ which is true. Did you mix it up in the title?

Comment: And it's the log which is squared, or its argument?

Comment: Yes i am sorry don't know what happend  to me so many dumb mistakes

Comment: The log is squared

Comment: I want to prove O

Comment: @yuval Why do you have an omega in the title??

Comment: I want to prove log^2(n) is O(sqrt(n)) so its the same as sqrt(n) is omega(log^2(n))

Comment: @yuval Please rewrite your question, so that it is clear what you are asking. Take your time.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $\log x \le x$ for all $x>0$,
$$
\log x = 4\log \sqrt[4]{x} \le 4\sqrt[4]{x} \Rightarrow \log ^2 x \le 16\sqrt x.
$$
Can you prove that $\log x = \mathcal{O}(x^\alpha  )$ for any $\alpha>0$? Strictly speaking, the converse statement is $\sqrt{x}=\Omega(\log^2 x)$ and not $\sqrt{x}=\omega(\log^2 x)$, however both are correct.